# add_argument with variables does not work in python 3.4.2 argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Here is the user story.

1. Build the argument. standalone.

   ```
   parser.add_argument('-design_engineer', '-de');

   $test.py -design_engineer sbir
   Namespace(design_engineer, _de='sbir')
   ```
2. Build the arguments with variables.

   ```
   column_name = 'design_engineer';
   alias_n = 'de';
   parser.add_argument("-" + column_name + ", " + "-" + alias_n);

   $test.py -design_engineer sbir
   Namespace(design_engineer, _de='sbir')
   ```

Comment: Please try to fix the formatting of your question. It doesn't look anything like you probably intended, making it very difficult to read. Also, what exactly is your question? You've made some statements but haven't asked anything.

Comment: The comma is not part of the string..

Comment: `Namespace(design_engineer, _de='sbir')` looks like the attribute name is 'design_engineer, _de', the whole string.  Normally the short option flag is something like '-d', and the long '--design-engineer', with the resulting `dest` being 'design_engineer'.  You might also try an explicit `dest='design_enginerr'` parameter.

Comment: parser.add_argument('-design_engineer', '-de');

$test.py -design_engineer sbir
Namespace(design_engineer='sbir')

Comment: parser.add_argument('-design_engineer', '-de');
Namespace(design_engineer, _de='sbir')

Comment: 1)Build the argument. standalone
parser.add_argument('-design_engineer', '-de');
$test.py -design_engineer sbir
Namespace(design_engineer='sbir')

2)Build the arguments with variables.
column_name = 'design_engineer';
alias_n = 'de';
parser.add_argument("-" + column_name + ", " + "-" + alias_n);

$test.py -design_engineer sbir
Namespace(design_engineer, _de='sbir')

Issue :
Please observe the difference in the Namespace.

Comment: Add your comments to the original question; they'll be easier to read when indented properly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the comma into the string; you need to still produce two separate strings:

```
parser.add_argument("-" + column_name, "-" + alias_n)
```

Comment: column_name = 'design_engineer';
 alias_n = 'de';
 arg_var = "-" + column_name,;
 arg_var = arg_var + "-" + alias_n,;
Error:

raceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tssupdate.py", line 208, in <module>
    arg_var = (arg_var + "-" + alias_n,);
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Comment: Actually i am building the arguments dynamically from the variables.

Comment: You have commas in your values, making them tuples. Also, Python doesn't need all those semicolons, you can remove them.

Comment: argv_var = "-" + column_name, "-" + alias_n
parser.add_argument(argv_var);

Remove commas will work.  But namespace is printed wrongly.
Finally my requirent is i am reading the argument options from a xml file.
I will be framing a string based on conditions and will add that to add_argument.
Please help me on this.

Comment: That sounds like a new question. Create another post and be clear about your attempt, and include a [mcve] for us to help you with.

Comment: I think i need to wait for some more days to add new post. Stackoverflow will not allow me to add more posts at a time.One thing i want is how to frame add_argument. suppose say,  option,type,dest,action all are defined in xml file. I will read the xml file and i want to frame a add_argument command dynamicallcy by using those variables. Please give some sample with variables. do not required to read xml file. Think that u r storing it in variables. and frame add_argument.